# Can't find Grant Admin Consent

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm making a function that gets new access token by refresh token,

```
const getAccessToken = async refreshToken => {
  try {
    const accessTokenObj = await axios.post(
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token',
      querystring.stringify({
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
        client_id: 'xxxxx',
        client_secret: 'xxxxx',
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        resource: 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
        prompt: 'admin_consent'
      })
    );
    return accessTokenObj;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

but when I run my code, I got this error:

```
The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxxxx' named 'xxxxx'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
```

So I was following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent#grant-admin-consent-when-registering-an-app-in-the-azure-portal) to grant admin consent by I couldn't find `Grant Admin Consent` button in my application.

[image: a busy cat]

What I was missing? I'm using a personal account to create an application.

Comment: But I'm using a personal account to create an application. I used `App Registration` not `Enterprise Application`, so how can I grant consent?

Comment: I don't know, I just registered a personal account and create an application, so I'm not sure about `global administrator`, an `application administrator`....

Comment: Could you post a detail answer below? I'm very new with azure

Comment: Why do you want to add `Grant consent` ?Do you want to access graph API?

Comment: As I posted above, I want to get a new access token by refresh token, and that access token will be used to access MS Graph API such as upload file to OneDrive, convert file api...

Comment: For that you can add dedicated permission. Admin consent is not required for . in that case get rid of this line `prompt: admin_consent`

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your advice but it didn't work. I changed permission from `Application permissions` to `Delegated permissions` and remove `prompt: admin_consent` at my request, but the same error still happened. May be the problem from `resource: 'https://graph.microsoft.com' `, not sure

Comment: No resource is alright. Could you please try with tenant account?

Comment: I changed permission from `Application permissions` to `Delegated permissions`, I still couldn't find a `Grant Consent` button, its really weird https://i.imgur.com/6um8vZ4.png

Comment: Its because of personal account. personal account doesn't have that option. Need tenant account. You can try with tenant account. Its more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow below steps:

[image]

**Note:** With personal account you cannot get `Grant Consent` Option. you should have tenant account. After that you can add Personal account for that operation. Better you can try with `dedicated permission`

Comment: It seems like my `Users` page is different with yours https://i.imgur.com/H6g6cmt.png
And I can't find Directory Role :(

Comment: No problem add your user. In case of personal account add as guest then assign above role.

Comment: Its really weird. I got this notification `Unable to complete due to service connection error, please try again later.` and couldn't click anything

Comment: @TranB.V.Son Any progress?

Comment: I'm creating tenant account, I will update progress soon, thank you very much

Comment: That will be more convenient. Let me know if there any more concern. In that case without changing code  try application permission it will also work. I will also update answer for that.

Comment: I'm using tenant account and it worked perfectly, thank you for your supporting, sir!

Comment: absolutely sure sir!

Comment: Happy coding! Good luck